# IE9 behaves differently for the same CSS3 but different applications(WebFrom and MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I have two applications, one in ASP.Net 4.5 Web Forms and the other in ASP.Net 4.5 MVC). I used the same CSS3 for background for both as follows.
    background-color:#xxxxx;
    background-image:url("../Media/Background/xxxxxxxxx.gif");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;

But IE9 behaves differently for Web Form and MVC.

It can be seen in the following websites
www.DSW.DynamicWebApplication.Net (Web Form)
www.Weyni.DynamicWebApplication.Net (MVC)

Note: to understand the difference, check both websites in different browsers + IE9

Did I make any mistake or ....?

Answer (score 1):

Your Web Form site contains a tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

that isn't present in the MVC site.

In general, if you want the same result in the browser, you need to send the same HTML.

Comment: If you created a new 4.5 site in MVC it will also have the Bootstrap library included I believe - this could subtly change the defaults your CSS code is being based on.

Comment: @All the web form site is working like MVC site on development machine  but they behave differently when deployed.

Comment: @Gizachew - then you should compare the HTML sent by the deployed version.  E.g. "View Source" from your browser, and compare the HTML and included files.

Comment: @Joe - you are right, the HTML sent by the deployed versions are different. it is also different in 'development' version. and I don't claim it has to be the same.  by the way, the mvc site has the same problem as web form site in mobile browsers.